# On-off button function two condition

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

Only working if side. El

```js
    let openedTopAdsButton = true;

    const onOffCollapsedAds = () => {
      if (openedTopAdsButton) {
        document.querySelector(".collapsed-top-ads").style.opacity = "0";
        document.querySelector(".collapsed-top-ads").style.height = "0";
        document.querySelector(".collapsed-top-ads-button").textContent =
          "show";
        openedTopAdsButton = false;
      } else {
        document.querySelector(".collapsed-top-ads").style.opacity = "1";
        document.querySelector(".collapsed-top-ads").style.height = "auto";
        document.querySelector(".collapsed-top-ads-button").textContent =
          "close";
openedTopAdsButton = true;
      }
    };
```

```css
    .collapsed-top-ads {
      width: 10%;
    height:100px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      height: auto;
      transition: all 0.5 ease-in-out;
    }
    .collapsed-top-ads-img {
      width: 100%;
    }
    .collapsed-top-ads-img img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: contain !important;
    }
    .collapsed-top-ads-button {
      width: 100%;

      border: none;
      height: 30px;
      background-color: white;
      font-weight: 500;

      transition: all 0.5 ease-in-out;
    }
```

```html
      <div class="collapsed-top-ads">
            <div class="collapsed-top-ads-img">
              <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1502802652777779200/6_hqg9tl_400x400.png" alt="british-turks">
            </div>

          </div>
          <button onclick="onOffCollapsedAds()" class="collapsed-top-ads-button"close</button>
```

se condition doesnt work. whats wrong here? EDİT: I have attached the example upon request. I didn't get any changing result.  When I declare it from the outside, only the first condition is accepted as true and the other one is not triggered.

Comment: When does this get called? It looks like openTopAdsButton gets set on true every time the function gets triggered, thus it will never go into else.

Comment: Breakpoints and step by step execution might help you understand how it works

Comment: Please don't systematically vandalize *all* of your existing questions/answers.  If your intent is to abandon the Stack Overflow community, you can go ahead and do that.  But there's no need to break all of your old content on the way out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This condition will *always* be `true`:

```
let openedTopAdsButton = true;
if (openedTopAdsButton) {
  //...
}
```

Because when you define a variable to equal `true`, that variable will then equal `true`.

It *looks like* you are expecting the value of the variable to change over time for multiple calls to the `onOffCollapsedAds` function.  If that's the case then you don't want to re-define the variable and explicitly set it to `true` *on every call to the function*.  Instead, define the variable *outside* the function so its value can persist across function calls:

```
let openedTopAdsButton = true;

const onOffCollapsedAds = () => {
  if (openedTopAdsButton) {
    //...
    openedTopAdsButton = false;
  } else {
    //...
    openedTopAdsButton = true;
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I tried your solution but the result did not change

Comment: @usul93: [Works for me.](https://jsfiddle.net/e60xgudy/)  Can you provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @usul93: Your updated version never sets `openedTopAdsButton` back to `true`.  Which is why `openedTopAdsButton` never gets set back to `true`.  Why would you remove that line?

Comment: cause it didnt work anyway on my local. but edited again for you. and thanks again.

Comment: problem is false value doesnt work i think

Comment: @usul93: And now it works.  It looks like the ongoing problem was just a typo on your part, it no longer needs to be edited into the question.

Comment: no it doesnt work

Comment: @usul93: What "doesn't work" about it?  What functionality are you expecting vs. what you're observing?  If I continue to invoke a "click" event on your `<button>` element then it continues to toggle back and forth between the two different display states.  Perhaps you're just struggling to click the button because your styling sometimes partially hides it behind other elements?  You need to be more clear than "it doesn't work", and styling problems were never in the original scope of the question being asked.

Comment: I checked again after your comment. Changea couple css and then realize function is actually work. So problem was in css. I delete height attribute in css and just work with fucntion. Your answers really was helpful ty David.